# Webservice object fail handling

Tags: c#, exception, webservice-client

I have a problem regarding try catch when creating an object in C#.

My problem appears when an object is supposed to be created and the webservice which defines the object isn't available or has been modified.
That is the problem I would like my program to handle.

When I try to do this:

```
try
{
    var Customer = new Customer();
}
catch
{
      //handling the exception.
}
```

Later on in my program I need that particular object, but due to the try catch the object isn't available in all cases (of course when the try fails, the object isn't created).

**without if(customer != null)**

```
if (insertCustomer(lead, LS_TS, out Customer) == true)
{
    insert = true;
}
```

**with if(customer != null)**

```
if(customer != null)
{
    if (insertCustomer(lead, LS_TS, out Customer) == true)
    {
        insert = true;
    }
}
```

**No matter what, the compiler says: "The name 'Customer' does not exist in the current context**

How do I solve this problem? I need a program to be running all the time and when checking an object which isn't created then I need to exit the method and try again later.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"then I need to exit the method"_ - `return;`?

Comment: No that's not my problem.
try
{
  var Customer = new Customer();
}
catch
{
  //handling the exception.
}

customer.Name= 'name of customer';

Compiler says:

"The name 'customer' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: ```out Customer``` try this lowercase, like ```out customer```

Comment: Also, are all this pieces of code in the same function? Or are they different functions?

Comment: Sorry for that. Ment Customer.Name= ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
Customer customer = null;

try
{
    customer = new Customer();
}
catch
{
    // handling the exception.
}
```

and whenever you need to use the object customer you should do this

```
if(customer != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: As I see this, your answer only works without the try catch.
The compiler won't accept use of the customer object other places than the try {xxx}

Comment: That is very weird. What is the error the compiler is giving you?

Comment: I put more code in the initial display.
Please have a look there.